# Promise and await Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I've got a strange problem..
FIrst, take a look at my code:

This one is where I use my await..

```
case "detail": {
                const lineMessages = [];
                let item = await this.getItem(postback.id);
                let lineMessage = {
                        type: "text",
                        text: item.longDesc
                };
                lineMessages.push(lineMessage);
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    if(lineMessages != []) {
                        resolve(lineMessages);
                    }
                    else {
                        let error = new Error("Cannot catch item ${postback.id}");
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
```

This is the getItem(id) method..

```
    getItem(id) {
    return Item.find({_id: id}).exec();
}
```

But it turns out the text key on my lineMessage is undefined..
Then, the lineMessage is `LineMessages: [{"type":"text"}]` ( I once logged it on my console)
Why await doesn't stop the execution in my case?
It seems it tries to look up `item.longDesc` before `item` is resolved (just my guess tho).
Please help

Comment: Are you sure the `Item.find().exec()` method returns a `Promise`? From a first glance at the docu, it expects a callback instead.

Comment: @Sirko `await` will actually handle a non-promise value by just returning it.

Comment: @UncleDave I think he meant that it might be a callback function instead of a promise function, but I'm not sure that's the case here. Could be the case that `getItem` didn't actually find the item, or some other API misusage

Comment: @UncleDave It will, if the returned value is actually, what you're expecting. I assume here the return value is some other object and not a promise. Hence, the execution at that step does not wait for the `find()` operation to be finished.

Comment: Ah, true. If `exec` expects a callback then `await` won't do anything for you.

Comment: [According to the examples here,](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model) the exec function does appear to return a promise. In OP's case, it looks like the `item` variable is some kind of object, but doesn't have the `longDesc` property on it. @TerrySmith, what do you get when you `console.log(item)` after the `await`?

Comment: Unrelated: @Terry Smith: `lineMessages != []` can be more elegantly expressed as `lineMessages.length`.

Answer (score 0):

When you require mongoose you can pass native es6 Promise to mongoose options, then you can use native promises instead of mongoose queries

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise; // or you can use bluebird. Add this line in models and before connection to database

Item.find({_id: id}).exec() // shoud return native Promise
```

Or on mongoose connection options (globally)

```
const options = {
    promiseLibrary: global.Promise
};
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Mongoose queries is pretty weird. `Item.find({_id: id}).exec()` returs mongoose query, and **have .then()** method, **but its not native js promise!** 
When you add custom promiseLibrary to mongoose instance then `Item.find({_id: id}).exec()` returns native js Promise and work with async await.

Comment: its still `undefined`

Comment: You are shure that this.getItem(postback.id) call getItem(id) method?

Comment: Try this: change getItem function: `return Item.find({_id: id});` and in add exec to `let item = await this.getItem(postback.id).exec();`

Comment: By logging, it seems that `lineMessages` doesn't wait for the item.. I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure that in Item.model.js, after requiring mongoose you pass native promise to mongoose.Promise? 
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
... define schema and model, export`

Comment: And give me detail info about this.getItem(postback.id) object
`console.log(this.getItem(postback.id) instanceof Promise);`

Comment: Finally, I've got the answer. Item is an array actually containing a single object. I've been debugging the whole day and this is so embarassing. Thank you anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mongoose `findOne()` returns an array with a single object, not just an object.